# PHP foreach array push with key and value

Tags: php, foreach

I have this foreach here

```
<?php foreach($division as $value){
            $arraydivision[] = $value['name'];
        } ?>
```

but the keys come back as 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

I would like the keys to be also the names...I have tried

```
<?php foreach($division as $value){
            $arraydivision[] = $value['name'] => $value['name'];
        } ?>
```

But that didnt work, just gave me an error...anyone know why this is not working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PHP syntax for this is:

```
$arraydivision[$value['name']] = $value['name'];
```

Take a look at [PHP array documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), section `Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax`, there are also exmpales on how to use `unset()` and other details.

You also may find [documentation for `foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) interesting (especially secion on `array_expression as $key => $value` syntax).

Answer (score 9):

Assuming `$value['name']` is the *name* you want:

```
foreach($division as $value){
    $arraydivision[$value['name']] = $value['name'];
}
print_r($arraydivision);
```

**Note:** Seems odd to assign *key* and *value* the same. Maybe you wish to assign `$value`?